# PowerMock, mock a static method, THEN call real methods on all other statics

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm setting up mocking a class' static methods.  I have to do this in a `@Before`-annotated JUnit setup method.

My goal is to setup the class to call real methods, **except** for those methods I explicitly mock.

Basically:

```
@Before
public void setupStaticUtil() {
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticUtilClass.class);

  // mock out certain methods...
  when(StaticUtilClass.someStaticMethod(anyString())).thenReturn(5); 

  // Now have all OTHER methods call the real implementation???  How do I do this?
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that within `StaticUtilClass` the method `public static int someStaticMethod(String s)` unfortunately throws a `RuntimeException` if supplied with a `null` value.

So I can't simply go the obvious route of calling real methods as the default answer as below:

```
@Before
public void setupStaticUtil() {
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticUtilClass.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS); // Default to calling real static methods

  // The below call to someStaticMethod() will throw a RuntimeException, as the arg is null!
  // Even though I don't actually want to call the method, I just want to setup a mock result
  when(StaticUtilClass.someStaticMethod(antString())).thenReturn(5); 
}
```

I need to set the default Answer to call real methods on all other static methods **after** I mock the results from the method I'm interested in mocking.

Is this possible?

Comment: The matcher should probably be anyString() rather than antString()

Comment: @Nathan Adams - yep.  Updated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What are you looking for is called **partial mocking**.

In PowerMock you can use **mockStaticPartial** method.

In PowerMockito you can use stubbing, which will stub only the method defined and leave other unchanged:

```
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(StaticUtilClass.class, "someStaticMethod")).toReturn(5);
```

also don't forget about the

```
@PrepareForTest(StaticUtilClass.class)
```

Comment: I don't see either a stub() or a mockStaticPartial() method in my PowerMockito class.  Version 1.5.  In my version 1.9.5 Mockito class, I see a stub() method here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stub(T) however reading the docs I found this: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when(T) which notes that **when() is a successor of deprecated stub(Object)**, so I don't think that method is meant to be used anymore, and wouldn't do what I need regardless.

Comment: mockStaticPartial is defined for EasyMock - I didn't catch that you were asking explicitly for Mockito - http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html

Comment: stub is defined in MemberModifier which is a superclass of PowerMockito - it is there! - http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/support/membermodification/MemberModifier.html#stub%28java.lang.reflect.Method%29

Comment: Hi! Could you help? How stub method with specific arguments?

Answer (score 4):

Though I'm late to the party, but we can achieve partial mocking and override the default behavior of mocked object by explicitly specifying it.

Below example show how we can make `PowerMockito` to call real methods if behavior isn't defined explicitly:

e.g. `PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class, new CallsRealMethods());`