# JUnit missing behavior definition for STATIC method call

Tags: java, junit, powermock, parameterized

This is my test method:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@PrepareForTest(FilenameUtils.class)
public class Test {

    //code
    private final String datum;
    private final String expectedResult;

    public Test(String datum, String expectedResult){
        this.datum = datum;
        this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
    }

    @Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> generateData(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
      { ".jpg", "productimage..jpg" },
      { "jpg", "jpg.jpeg" },
      { "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog.jpeg", "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjump.jpeg" }
   });
 }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testSanitizeFilename(){
        PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(FilenameUtils.class, "getExtension" , "getBaseName");

        expect(FilenameUtils.getExtension(datum)).andReturn("jpeg").anyTimes();
        expect(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(datum)).andReturn("productimage").anyTimes();

        PowerMock.replay(FilenameUtils.class);

        String result = FileUtil.sanitizeFilename(datum, defaultName, contentType);

        PowerMock.verify(FilenameUtils.class);

        assertEquals(result, expectedResult);
    }
}
```

And this is the method to be tested:

```
public class FileUtil {

     //code

     public static String sanitizeFilename(String filename, ............) {
         //code here

         if (filename.length() > 100) {
             FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
             FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
         }

         return fileName;
     }
}
```

The code works only for the cases that the condition in FileUtil.sanitizeFilename is not true. If it is true (by passing a filename > 100 characters), then the following error occurs:

```
   Unexpected method call FilenameUtils.getExtension("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog.jpeg"):
 java.lang.AssertionError
   Unexpected method call FilenameUtils.getExtension("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogthequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog.jpeg"):
         at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
         at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.invoke(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:91)
         at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:105)
         at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:60)
         at org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getExtension(FilenameUtils.java)
         at com.eurodyn.ecatalogue.util.FileUtil.sanitizeFilename(FileUtil.java:235)
         at com.eurodyn.ecatalogue.ejb.session.others.AsyncFileDownloadManagerBeanTest.testSanitizeFilename(AsyncFileDownloadManagerBeanTest.java:130)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:52)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
         at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:885)
         at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
         at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
         at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
         at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
         at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
         at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

What is incorrect in my code?

**EDIT:**
I used Parameterized class in order to avoid the for loop.

I used PowerMock.mockStaticPartial for the static methods getBaseName and getExtension.

Comment: have you looked at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651138/powermock-mock-a-static-method-then-call-real-methods-on-all-other-statics ? Could  it be that you need partial mocking on static methods ?

Comment: Just a gut feeling for now - but `@PrepareForTest({FileUtil.class,` seems off as that is the class under test, right? And I don't get the "anyTimes()" calls on `expect(FilenameUtils` - is that verification code? Maybe try without those and do additional verification after.

Comment: @Thierry yes I've seen it and I've tried it by adding 

PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(FilenameUtils.class, "getExtension" , "getBaseName");

but still got the same error.

Comment: @Jan I have removed the FileUtil class from the annotation as you suggested. anyTimes() is needed because if I do not add it, then in case it is not called i get the error "Expectation failure on verify: expected 1, actual 0".

Comment: And did that (removing FileUtil) change anything?

Comment: Check here: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic the sequence there is; mockStatic, expect() replay() DO THE TEST verify() do verification.

Comment: @Jan thank you, I tried it, but now I get the error "Unexpected method call FilenameUtils.getExtension(..."

Comment: @FunnyJava could you update your code to actual state. The stacktrace and your code don't match...

Comment: @guilhermerama done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it worked for me

```
@Test
public void testSanitizeFilename() {
    PowerMock.mockStatic(FilenameUtils.class);
    EasyMock.expect(FilenameUtils.getExtension(anyString())).andReturn("jpeg").anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(anyString())).andReturn("jpeg").anyTimes();
    PowerMock.replayAll();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileUrls.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("KEY: " + entry.getKey());
        String result = FileUtil.sanitizeFilename(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        assertEquals(result, entry.getValue());     
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Note that I modified sanitizeFilename some to get working code for me. And I used

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

instead of `RunWith` - but as I had all your errors before this might fix your stuff as well.

Seems like mocking inside the loop was no good idea to begin with - once I moved the mocks out of the loop it got me somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I used the PowerMockRule after I changed to Parameterized runner, it was quite helpful!

The basic change I made though, was using PowerMock.mockStaticPartialNice instead of PowerMock.mockStaticPartial and I got it to work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Many ways to Rome ;-)