# powermockito.when().thenReturn() - calls mocked function

Tags: java, powermockito

Using PowerMockito to setup a test containing a private method ala [this](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#A_full_example_of_partial_mocking_of_a_private_method).

Class:

```
public class SomeMod {
    public void somefunc() {
        Logger.debug("somefunc");
        ...
        privFunction(param);
        ...
    }

    private void privFunction(param) {
        Logger.debug("privFunction");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeMod.class})
public class somemod_test {
    ...
    @Test public void test0() {
        SomeMod_spy somemod = spy(new SomeMod());
        PowerMockito.when(somemod, "privFunction", "param").thenReturn(someMockedValue);

        ...
        somemod.somefunc();
    }

}
```

When I run this and set breakpoints on both Logger.debug statements Im seeing the `privFunction` get hit before the `somefunc`.  If I comment out the call to `somemod.somefunc()` in the test, the `privFunction` is *still* getting hit.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Edit:

I used `PowerMockito.when().thenReturn()` instead of the recommeded `PowerMockito.doReturn().when()` syntax as the former throws NPE and **UnfinishedStubbingException**. This suggests that my test environment isn't setup properly. Not sure where to look to fix this.

Comment: Answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651138/powermock-mock-a-static-method-then-call-real-methods-on-all-other-statics

Answer (score 3):

After taking a short walk and then a fresh look at the code the problem / answer is the linkage of the **mock**/**spy** calls to setup the `doReturn`.

Instead of:

`spy(new SomeMod())`

Use:

`PowerMockito.spy(new SomeMod())`

This will setup the test(s) according to the docs.

Comment: Depends on the import statements, but yeah, I missed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the doReturn().when() syntax to keep the mocked method from being called.  It's the only way I know of to do it.