# Static method returns empty value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to add a test class for a static method :

```
class SomeClass {

    public static int getLoginPage() {
    if (otherStaticMethod()) {
      return Screen.FOO;
    }
    return Screen.BAR;
  }
}
```

Note that FOO and BAR have values differents of zero.

My test class :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class})
public class SomeClass_getLoginPage {

  @Test
  public void testgetLoginPage() {    
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);    

    Mockito.when(SomeClass.otherStaticMethod()).thenReturn(true);

    assertTrue(SomeClass.getLoginPage() == Screen.FOO);


    Mockito.when(SomeClass.otherStaticMethod()).thenReturn(false);

    assertTrue(SomeClass.getLoginPage() == Screen.BAR);
  }
}
```

But when the method `otherStaticMethod` is called, the method `getLoginPage` returns `0`, where it should return `FOO` or `BAR`. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerMock, mock a static method, THEN call real methods on all other statics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651138/powermock-mock-a-static-method-then-call-real-methods-on-all-other-statics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use overloaded `spy` method instead of actually mocking the entire class.

```
PowerMockito.spy(SomeClass.class);
```

Now by default all the static method will run with real implementation until you actually mock one of them.

The reason you get `0` is because by `mockStatic` you mock all the static methods and by default an invocation of an `int` returning method, would result in that value (if not explicitly specified otherwise).