# PowerMockito mockStatic gives MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: powermockito

I am trying to mockStatic method using PowerMockito , where I tried some options to mockStatic for a class, resulting in different exceptions.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Base64.class})
public class BqClientFactoryTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetBigQueryClient() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Base64.class);
        Base64.Decoder mockDecoder = mock(Base64.Decoder.class);
        when(Base64.getDecoder()).thenReturn(mockDecoder);
```

This resulted in `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:`

I used another example like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Base64.class})
public class BqClientFactoryTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetBigQueryClient() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Base64.class);
        Base64.Decoder mockDecoder = mock(Base64.Decoder.class);
        doReturn(mockDecoder).when(Base64.class, "getDecoder");
```

which gives me

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
```

If I use

```
BDDMockito.given(Base64.getDecoder()).willReturn(mockDecoder);
```

from [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) , it still returns `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException`

I tried to check similar questions on SO, they haven't seemed to help.
Any help resolving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it following this, all other solutions didn't work for me. It is difficult to search for this solution, since there are too many on SO on the same.

[PowerMockito mock single static method and return object inside another static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054243/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object-inside-another-static-m?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [PowerMock, mock a static method, THEN call real methods on all other statics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651138/powermock-mock-a-static-method-then-call-real-methods-on-all-other-statics/14651766#14651766)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Base64.class})
public class BqClientFactoryTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetBigQueryClient() throws Exception {
        Base64.Decoder mockDecoder = mock(Base64.Decoder.class);
        stub(method(Base64.class, "getDecoder")).toReturn(mockDecoder);
```

Comment: Since I have found this solution now, not sure what is the right thing to do, since it seems a duplicate. But difficult to find in so many questions and answers on SO on the same topic. This one adding to it.